# Creating a large background and moving it with your finger

Tags: android

I am designing a Game and have a large background.  The background it a lot bigger than the phone display so the user will only have a small "View" of the background.  They will be able to move around by scrolling with their finger.

How do i go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My application does this.
It is open-source so feel free to copy-and-paste:
http://code.google.com/p/androidbigimage

Comment: I just tried this and it does not work.  I was using the 1.6 emulator.  The image displays but I cannot zoom in or out

Comment: Actually I got this working by changing the scalType to matrix

Comment: Indeed, I wrote the code for 1.5 and did not test for 1.6
So you got it working by changing the scalType to matrix?
What changes do you mean exactly?  

If you could send me the fixed code, I would correct my code (open source of course).
My email is nicolas.raoul at Google's famous mail service. If you know how to use GitHub that would be even better :-)
Thanks a lot!